# After hitting cancel in a MFMessageComposeViewController nothing happens

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, sms, messageui

After though that after using `MFMailComposeViewController` the move to `MFMessageComposeViewController` was straight foward, but there is a catch.

Suppose this code:

```
MFMessageComposeViewController* mySMS = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
[mySMS setDelegate:self];
[self presentModalViewController:mySMS animated:YES];
```

It works this way for mails, but in sms you should set different the delegate to an internal structure like this:

```
[SMS setMessageComposeDelegate:self];
```

Hope you don not get stuck on this as I did early today.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to Implement the delegate method `-(void)mailComposeController(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult (MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error:`

And inside it you should dismiss it yourself:

```
-(void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error 
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; 
}
```

Comment: The code you mentioned is for MFMailComposer Class. The question was asked specifically to MFMessageComposer.

Comment: You need to use the following for the MFMessageComposer: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate_protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate/messageComposeViewController:didFinishWithResult:

Answer (score 0):

You can see MFMailComposeResult in Apple documentation

```
  enum MFMailComposeResult {
    MFMailComposeResultCancelled,
    MFMailComposeResultSaved,
    MFMailComposeResultSent,
    MFMailComposeResultFailed
 };
 typedef enum MFMailComposeResult MFMailComposeResult;
```

And you must dismiss controller by yourself in delegate method

```
 - (void) mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller          didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error
 {
  switch (result){
    case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
        NSLog(@"Mail cancelled");
        break;
    case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
        NSLog(@"Mail saved");
        break;
    case MFMailComposeResultSent:
        NSLog(@"Mail sent");
        break;
    case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
        NSLog(@"Mail sent failure: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        break;
    default:
        break;
   }
// Close the Mail Interface
   [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```